# How to select a child div on button click using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to select the 'chat-box-frnd-cnt' div to apply a fadeOut, I've tried using:

```
$(".chat-box, html, body").on("click", '.submitchatnew', function(){
$(this).parent().next('.chat-box-frnd').find('.chat-box-frnd-cnt').fadeOut(500);
});
```

but it doesn't work

HTML:

```
<div class="chat-box">
         <div id="consubmitchatnew">
            <input class="submitchatnew" type="submit" value="" />
            </div>
                        <div class="chat-box-frnd">
                        <div class="chat-box-frnd-img"></div>
                        <div class="chat-box-frnd-cnt">
                        <div class="cbf-cnt"><h4></h4></div></div>
                        <div class="chat-box-frnd-cpng"></div>
                        <div class="chat-box-frnd-nm"><h3></h3></div>
                        <div class="cb-frnd-divisor"></div>
                        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/skyhvw3r/. What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [JQuery`s documentation](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

you should use `$(".chat-box").children(".chat-box-frnd-cnt").fadeOut(500);`